# Where to find the actual value of variable POSTMAN?

Tags: postman

In postman `{{url}}:8001/api/{{version}}/auth/login` Where can i find the actual value of `{{url}}` in `POSTMAN`

Comment: You have to pass the value of `url` as a parameter in `POST` required. Its up to your app, how could we know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `{{url}}` in your request path and this is red, this means that you do not have a environment or global variable value set.

[image: No Var Set]

If you have a value set for this variable name, it will be orange and by hovering over the `{{url}}` value, you will see the set value displayed in a pop up box.

This can also be viewed in the 'Environment Quick View' by pressing the 'eye' icon, on the right side of the application.

[image: Variable]

More info on Postman variables can be found here: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables

Comment: Than you so much :-)